# android application lunching time issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have a project from my friend. The problem is that if I run it on my PC I receive the following errors:

```
[2012-04-10 11:19:28 - myapp] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2012-04-10 11:19:28 - myapp] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-04-10 11:19:28 - muapp] Launch canceled!
```

What can be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you have included **Maps** functionality in your project. So to run this project, you have to install Google APIs through the SDK Manager and create AVD using that api or you can run on your device directly.

[image]

Comment: 100% agree, and this will be the solution.

Comment: any link for that api u know ??